# Oracle SQL inner join not returning records with blank values

Tags: sql, oracle

I am joining two tables together, but the result set does not include blank rows.  The query below does not return columns with null values.  Why is that?

```
SELECT
  table1.FE_KEY
 ,table2.CV_VALUE
 ,table2.CV_UOM AS EST_ISENTROPIC_POWERUoM
 ,CVDATA1.CV_VALUE
 ,CVDATA1.CV_UOM AS VAPOUR_OR_GAS_HANDLEUoM
 ,CVDATA2.CV_VALUE
 ,CVDATA2.CV_UOM AS NORMAL_FLOW_RATEUoM     
FROM
  ((table1 FULL LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.ID = table2.FE_ID)
  INNER JOIN table2 CVDATA1 ON table1.ID = CVDATA1.FE_ID)
  INNER JOIN table2 CVDATA2 ON table1.ID = CVDATA2.FE_ID    
WHERE ((table1.FE_KEY) Like '6-K-%')
  AND ((table2.CV_CODE)='EST_ISENTROPIC_POWER')
  AND ((CVDATA1.CV_CODE)='VAPOUR_OR_GAS_HANDLE')
  AND ((CVDATA2.CV_CODE)='NORMAL_FLOW_RATE')
```

Comment: Which column(s) do you know to have null values?

Comment: Your joins and `where` filters are filtering out the non-matching rows.  It is unclear what you really want -- `full join` with filtering is tricky.  Sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation would all help.

Comment: Some of table2.CV_VALUE ,table2.CV_UOM have null values. Sample data is large, can't be able to post it here. I want all values for table2.CV_VALUE ,table2.CV_UOM (whether null or have data) that matches id=fe-id

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include rows where FE_KEY or CV_CODE are null, then you need to explicitly include those. You also seem to have some extra parentheses that aren't needed.  Try this reworked version:

```
SELECT
  TABLE1.FE_KEY
 ,TABLE2.CV_VALUE
 ,TABLE2.CV_UOM AS EST_ISENTROPIC_POWERUOM
 ,CVDATA1.CV_VALUE
 ,CVDATA1.CV_UOM AS VAPOUR_OR_GAS_HANDLEUOM
 ,CVDATA2.CV_VALUE
 ,CVDATA2.CV_UOM AS NORMAL_FLOW_RATEUOM
FROM
  (
   (TABLE1 FULL LEFT JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.ID = TABLE2.FE_ID)
   INNER JOIN TABLE2 CVDATA1 ON TABLE1.ID = CVDATA1.FE_ID
  )
  INNER JOIN TABLE2 CVDATA2 ON TABLE1.ID = CVDATA2.FE_ID
WHERE (TABLE1.FE_KEY IS NULL OR TABLE1.FE_KEY LIKE '6-K-%')
  AND (TABLE2.CV_CODE IS NULL OR TABLE2.CV_CODE = 'EST_ISENTROPIC_POWER')
  AND (CVDATA1.CV_CODE IS NULL OR CVDATA1.CV_CODE = 'VAPOUR_OR_GAS_HANDLE')
  AND (CVDATA2.CV_CODE IS NULL OR CVDATA2.CV_CODE = 'NORMAL_FLOW_RATE')
```

Comment: This is the output I am expecting.

FE_KEY CV_VALUE EST_ISENTROPIC_POWERUOM CV_VALUE_1 VAPOUR_OR_GAS_HANDLEUOM CV_VALUE_2 NORMAL_FLOW_RATEUOM
6-K-1201 445 kW   Regeneration gas kg/s
6-K-1410 47000 kW 266.3  NO kg/s
6-K-1411 30000 kW 266.3  NO kg/s
6-K-1430 70456 kW 662.19  PROCESS GAS kg/s
6-K-1450   15.61  End Flash Gas

But I get this

FE_KEY CV_VALUE EST_ISENTROPIC_POWERUOM CV_VALUE_1 VAPOUR_OR_GAS_HANDLEUOM CV_VALUE_2 NORMAL_FLOW_RATEUOM
6-K-1410 47000 kW NO  266.3 kg/s
6-K-1411 30000 kW NO  266.3 kg/s
6-K-1430 70456 kW PROCESS GAS  662.19 kg/s
removes columns with no values

Comment: Thanks Joseph. The reworked code returned no rows.

Comment: @CAwaibe, sorry I think I had an error in my version of the WHERE clause; the last condition referred to "CVDATA1." when it should have been "CVDATA2".  Try it now; let me know if it returns rows for you.

Comment: I already corrected it. It didn't return any rows

Comment: @CAwaibe, does the original query still return rows?

Comment: Yes, with full out joins or left joins.
providing tables values here is difficult.

Comment: providing tables values here is difficult.
The main problem is what join will I use to get results that includes null values from cvdata1 and cvdata2. Rows where CVDATA1.CV_VALUE and CVDATA2.CV_VALUE do not have values (Null) are not returned. I want CVDATA1.CV_VALUE and CVDATA2.CV_VALUE with null or no null to be returned as path of the result. 
key             value1  value2
C-K-1200    45        NULL
C-K-1450    NULL   NULL
C-K-1300    50        70
C-K-1800    NULL   36

Comment: @CAwaibe the key rule is that NULL is not equal to anything, not even itself.  If you want to include nulls, use the keyword IS NULL.  if you want to exclude nulls, use IS NOT NULL.  I hope that general guidance helps, since it's difficult to see the full context in this editing space.  Best of luck to you!

Comment: Hi Joseph, Thanks for your comments. Pls what is the best way to combine these scripts.  
1st - returns 4 rows
SELECT TABLE1.FE_KEY, CVDATA.CV_VALUE, CVDATA.CV_UOM AS EST_ISENTROPIC_POWERUom
FROM TABLE1 left join CVDATA ON TABLE1.ID = CVDATA.FE_ID 
WHERE ((TABLE1.FE_KEY) Like '6-K-%') AND ((CVDATA.CV_CODE) ='EST_ISENTROPIC_POWER');

2nd - Returns 5 rows
SELECT TABLE1.FE_KEY, CVDATA.CV_VALUE, CVDATA.CV_UOM AS MAX_TEMP_COMPRESSIONUom
FROM TABLE1 left join CVDATA ON TABLE1.ID = CVDATA.FE_ID
WHERE ((TABLE1.FE_KEY) Like '6-K-%') AND ((CVDATA.CV_CODE) ='MAX_TEMP_COMPRESSION');

Comment: @CAwaibe try this, let me know if it gives you what you expect

SELECT
  TABLE1.FE_KEY
 ,CVDATA.CV_VALUE
 ,CASE WHEN CVDATA.CV_CODE = 'MAX_TEMP_COMPRESSION' THEN CVDATA.CV_UOM ELSE NULL END AS MAX_TEMP_COMPRESSIONUOM
 ,CASE WHEN CVDATA.CV_CODE = 'EST_ISENTROPIC_POWER' THEN CVDATA.CV_UOM ELSE NULL END AS EST_ISENTROPIC_POWERUOM
FROM
  TABLE1
  LEFT JOIN CVDATA ON TABLE1.ID = CVDATA.FE_ID
WHERE TABLE1.FE_KEY Like '6-K-%'
  AND CVDATA.CV_CODE  IN ('MAX_TEMP_COMPRESSION','EST_ISENTROPIC_POWER')

Comment: YES, there almost. the script produced this.
FE_KEY     CV_VALUE    COMPRESSIONUOM  TROPIC_POWERUOM
6-K-1201 200              DegC                         NULL
6-K-1201 445              NULL                          kW
6-K-1410 170              DegC                         NULL  
6-K-1410 47000      NULL                         kW
6-K-1411 200              DegC                        NULL  
6-K-1411 30000     NULL                        kW
6-K-1430 150             DegC                     NULL
6-K-1430 70456     NULL                    kW
6-K-1450 180     DegC                    NULL

Comment: This is my expectation from the script. Like a form of grouping on fe-key. Can you modify the script it a bit. Rows expected is 5 
FE_KEY      CV_VALUE  CV_VALUE1  COMPRESSIONUOM   TROPIC_POWERUOM
6-K-1201  200            445                     DegC                       KW
6-K-1410  170            47000                   DegC                      KW  
6-K-1411  200            30000                   DegC                      KW  
6-K-1430  150           70456                   DegC               KW
6-K-1450 180           NULL                    DegC                      NULL

Comment: Source Tables

TABLE1
FE_KEY    ID
6-K-1201  512623
6-K-1410  512624
6-K-1411  512625
6-K-1430  512785
6-K-1201  512623
6-K-1410  512624
6-K-1411  512625
6-K-1430  512785
6-K-1450  512792

Comment: Source Table
CVDATA
FE_ID     CV_CODE                              CV_VALUE   CV_UOM
512623    EST_ISENTROPIC_POWER   445              KW
512624    EST_ISENTROPIC_POWER   47000          KW   
512625    EST_ISENTROPIC_POWER   30000          KW
512785    EST_ISENTROPIC_POWER   70456          KW
512623    MAX_TEMP_COMPRESSION   200          DegC
512624    MAX_TEMP_COMPRESSION   170          DegC
512625    MAX_TEMP_COMPRESSION   200          DegC
512785    MAX_TEMP_COMPRESSION   150          DegC
512792    MAX_TEMP_COMPRESSION   180          DegC

Comment: Hello @joseph, Is there any update on your script using the 2 source tables I posted.

Comment: @CAwaibe Sorry but I am not going to be able to invest any more time in this issue; I can only encourage you to explore it yourself.  Perhaps if you post it in a separate question, someone else will pick it up with further steps.  Best wishes and good luck.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your support